# how to encode dart image object with base64

Tags: flutter, dart, base64

I want to encode an Image object (not from a file) with base64

Eg: this code `Image img = Image.memory(base64Decode(decoded(image)));` shows how to convert base64 string to Image Object, then how can i reverse this operation ?

Answer (score 0):

Image is a widget, so can't really convert it to base64 string;
Could do it with file:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
....

String base64String = base64Encode(file.readAsBytesSync());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
  var image = BASE64.decode(img.toString());
    Image.memory(image)
```